# Corresponding word for “wet” for diapers

Tags: phrase-request, adjectives

"My diaper is wet." my kid told me.
If he pooped in his diaper, can "wet" be used?

How to convey the message if he pooped in diaper?

Comment: One word that corresponds with _wet_ is _soiled_. It’s a bit formal for a young child, but it might be worth sharing in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wet* can also be used since, at least technically, it is *wet* and it will feel *wet* to him.
Maybe you could teach him to say

> I pooped.

or

> Stinky.

versus

> I peed.

then he would know the difference (might possibly be helpful to you too!).

Answer (score 4):

I assume you wanted to keep the *my diaper is [word]* form.

---

Yes, you can use *wet*, but I would expect *full* or *soiled*.
*Soiled* and *full* don't necessarily mean that the diaper is filled with poop, but I believe it is strongly suggested.

I prefer *my diaper is full*, but I noticed that the word *poopy* was commonly used in various sites, like [here](http://www.parents.com/advice/babies/diapering/how-often-should-i-change-my-babys-diaper/)

> Q: How often should diapers be changed?
>   A: Well, poopy diapers should be changed as soon as it is clear that your baby has left you a gift.

and [here](http://www.whattoexpect.com/forums/babys-first-year/topic/diaper-change-middle-of-night.html)

> I only change if they are very wet or poopy. Changing my girls' diapers also wakes them up.

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poopy+diaper%2Cfull+diaper&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoopy%20diaper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20diaper%3B%2Cc0), *poopy diaper* has gained more popularity than *full diaper* in recent years. I don't know how common this is, but I think

> My diaper is poopy.

sounds perfectly fine and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with using *wet* for either one. Compare a common phrase adults use, "I need to use the restroom." In many situations it would be awkward to say whether it was pee or poop. However as Peter pointed out, it might be helpful to you to teach your kid to alert you about what to expect when you open the "package." A common way to distinguish the two that is socially acceptable and considered polite is to say "number one" for urine and "number two" for feces.

> Person 1: "I need to go to the bathroom."
>   Person 2:  "Number one or number two?"
>   Person 1: "Number one" (pee)